# Summing lists in dataframe cells

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframes containing list cells:

```
a=pd.DataFrame([[[1,0,1],[0,1,0]],[[0,0,1],[0,1,0]],[[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]])
b=pd.DataFrame([[[0,0,1],[0,1,0]],[[0,0,1],[0,1,0]],[[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]])
c=pd.DataFrame([[[1,0,1],[0,0,0]],[[1,0,0],[0,1,0]],[[1,0,1],[0,0,0]]])
```

How do I add them position wise? e.g `[1,0,1] + [0,0,1 ] = [1,0,2]`

All I have done so far will sum the list to one number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `numpy` `array`

```
out = a.applymap(np.array) + b.applymap(np.array)
Out[135]: 
           0          1
0  [1, 0, 2]  [0, 2, 0]
1  [0, 0, 2]  [0, 2, 0]
2  [0, 0, 2]  [0, 2, 0]
```